# Ignore an exception in an API controller so that the controller still processes the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a simple controller than processes a POST request and then sends out an email.

I want to ignore any exceptions caused by the function that handles sending out the email so that I can still process the order.

I tried putting in an empty catch block, but it still stops everything and throws a 500 error to the client if there is a problem with sending the email.

Here is what I tried that didn't work:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessOrder([FromBody] CreateNewOrder order)
{
    '  *** do stuff with order and process

    try
    {
        SendThankYouEmail(product.Name);
    } catch  { }


    return Ok();


}
```

Is there a way to send the OK even if the function SendThankYouEmail failed?

Thanks!

Comment: Try following a producer-consumer pattern with a queue ina background hosted service. Something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks

Comment: I don't see how what you describe can happen. The catch all should be swallowing your exception

Comment: Are you sure that's where the exception is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, it is a bad design and should never be followed, you can do this workaround:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessOrder([FromBody] CreateNewOrder order)
{
    '  *** do stuff with order and process

    try
    {      
       SendThankYouEmail(product.Name);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       // Swallow the exception by logging it somewhere.
       return Ok();
    }    

    return Ok();        
}
```